# Can someone explain this shiftwise/Long tinkering output?

Tags: java, long-integer, bit-shift

### Run 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("shiftwise Example A = " + (0x47494638 << 32));

        long someNumber = 0x47494638;
        long otherNumber = someNumber << 32;

        System.out.println("shiftwise Example B = " + otherNumber);



    }
```

**Output:** 
shiftwise Example A = 1195984440 
shiftwise Example B = 5136714056324874240

### Run 2: (I just specified 'L' in Example A):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("shiftwise Example A = " + (0x47494638L << 32));

        long someNumber = 0x47494638;
        long otherNumber = someNumber << 32;

        System.out.println("shiftwise Example B = " + otherNumber);



    }
```

**Output:** 
shiftwise Example A = 5136714056324874240
shiftwise Example B = 5136714056324874240

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify the `L` suffix, then the constant literal value will be considered an `int`, and this text from [§15.19 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) applies:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator `&` ([§15.22.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)) with the mask value `0x1f` (`0b11111`). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `31`, inclusive.

Your left shift by 32 bits is therefore converted to a shift of *zero* bits, i.e. no change.

Answer (score 1):

The value is considered to be an int, which can be simulated like this:

### Run 3:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("shiftwise Example A = " + (0x47494638 << 32));

    int someNumber = 0x47494638;
    long otherNumber = someNumber << 32;

    System.out.println("shiftwise Example B = " + otherNumber);
}
```

**Output:**

> shiftwise Example A = 1195984440
>   shiftwise Example B = 1195984440